# Finding kernel and image of a linear transformation (polynomial)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following linear transformation: $D : V(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow V(\mathbb{R}) $ defined by:

$$ D:p(x)=ax^3 +bx^2 + cx + d \mapsto Dp(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c$$

And I want to find the kernel and the image of the transformation. Regarding the kernel, I have done the following

$$\operatorname{ker}(D) =  \{ Dp(x) = 0 \mid x \in V\} $$

$$ p(x)=ax^3 +bx^2 + cx + d = Dp(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c = 0 $$

Which can be solved through the quadratic formula. Is the answer then:

$$\operatorname{ker}(D) = \left\{\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-3ac}}{3a} \right\}$$

And what about the image? I know that $\operatorname{Im}(D) = \{ Dp(x) \mid x \in V \}$, but how can I show it?

Comment: What do you mean by $V(\mathbb{R})$ I think your linear transformation is the derivate, but by do you only take polynomials of degree 3 ?

Comment: Since D takes polynomials, its kernel should be polynomials but here your kernel is in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. I don’t think you want $=$ between  $ax^3 +bx^2 + cx + d$ and $Dp(x) $

Comment: Hint: rewrite the linear transformation as a matrix, and then calculate kernel and image from the matrix. You’ll want to re-translate the results back to the domain (polynomials).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, your solution is wrong.

I assume that $V(\Bbb R)$ denotes the set of all polynomials
with coefficients in $\Bbb R$ and degree at most $3$.

By definition,
$$\ker(D)=\{p(x)\in V(\Bbb R)\vert D(p(x))=0\}.$$
Equivalently,
$$\ker(D)=\{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\vert D(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R\}.$$
Note that
$$D(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=0\Rightarrow3ax^2+2bx+c=0.$$
Since $1,x,x^2$ is linearly independent, it follows that $a=0,b=0$, and $c=0$. Therefore,
$$\boxed{\ker(D)=\{d\vert d\in\Bbb R\}}.$$
Thus, the kernel of $D$ is the set of all constant polynomials. If we want, we can also present our result as
$$\boxed{\ker(D)=\{p:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\vert p(x)=a_0, \text{with} \   a_0\in\Bbb R\}}.$$

By definition,
$$\text{Im}(D)=\{D(p(x))\vert p(x)\in V(\Bbb R)\}.$$
Since $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\Rightarrow D(p(x))=3ax^2+2bx+c$, we have
$$\boxed{\text{Im}(D)=\{3ax^2+2bx+c\vert a,b,c\in\Bbb R\}}.$$
Thus, the image of $D$ is the set of all polynomials
with coefficients in $\Bbb R$ and degree at most $2$. If we want, we can also present our result as
$$\boxed{\text{Im}(D)=\{p:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\vert p(x)=a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0, \text{with} \ a_2,a_1,a_0\in\Bbb R\}}.$$

Comment: I feel like the characterization of the kernel could be made a little clearer, since the kernel consists of functions, and not of scalars. I also feel like the representation of the image could be done better, since in reality the image is just all quadratics over the reals; there's no real need for those superfluous coefficients. It loses that qualitative statement and intuition that the derivative maps cubics onto quadratics and is in fact a surjective mapping, by superficially insisting upon a particular form. Perhaps a mere matter of taste though.

Comment: @PrincessEev Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 6):

Your answer for the kernel is not correct. The kernel is going to be the polynomials $p$ sent to $0$ under $D$, i.e. those with $Dp=0$. You naively solved for the variable $x$, but that is about assigning a particular value to $x$. You need to find the polynomials with $Dp=0$, not solve a quadratic equation; you will arrive a set of polynomials, not a set of $x$ values that are the root of some equation.

> **Hint:** $Dp$ is sending a polynomial to its derivative $p'$. What functions have derivative equal to zero?

To figure out the image, you need to figure out what $D$ is really sending polynomials to. Based on the previous hint, you should have a guess of what happens to a polynomial $p$ and in particular its degree; so you should be able to guess "the image is all polynomials of degree $N$" (for some number $N$ you should determine). Then you just need to show that each of those polynomials has a preimage under $D$, i.e. for each $q$ in the image construct a $p$ such that $Dp=q$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Since it must be a function with derivative equal to zero, that must mean the function is constant. So the answer must be 3a+2b+c = 0, then right? ()={3a+2b+c / a,b,c∈} ?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak -- That is incorrect. The domain of $D$ is cubic polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$, so the kernel cannot be $\mathbb{R}$, but instead a subset of those cubic polynomials. It's more of a technicality (we are representing functions, not numbers).

Comment: @AriSamueli -- You likewise have described a kernel that is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, not a subset of the domain of $D$ (a subset of the set of cubic polynomials). You are right in that $p$ must be a constant polynomial for it have $Dp=0$, and hence $a=b=c=0$ and $d$ can be anything. Really, then, if we let $V(\mathbb{R})$ denote these cubics, then
$$
\text{ker}(D) = \{ ax^3+bx^2+cx+d \in V(\mathbb{R}) \mid a=b=c=0 \}
$$
(or you could really just literally say "the set of constant functions over $\mathbb{R}$" and be right).